# $p$-adics with the least upper-bound property

Tags: analysis, order-theory, p-adic-number-theory

It is well-known (I believe?) that the $p$-adics do not admit an ordering in the 'usual sense', the "usual sense" being a *total* order that is compatible with the field operations.  I do not want to require that an ordering be a total order, however.  In fact, I only require that it be a pre-order (though I believe it turns out to be a partial order).

Let $x\in \mathbb{Q}_p$ and define $x>0$ iff $x$ is a finite sum of powers of $p$ (the idea is that numbers which are non-zero absolute values should positive, and hence so should sums of them).  I believe this should be a partial order on $\mathbb{Q}_p$ that is compatible with the field operations (i.e., $x\leq y$ implies $x+z\leq y+z$ and $x,y\geq 0$ implies $xy\geq 0$).

Does $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with this ordering have the least upper-bound property?  (I apologize in advance if this question is overly easy; my understanding of the $p$-adics is not as strong as it probably should be.)

Comment: Seems to me as though one easily constructs two negatives whose sum is positive under your definitions.

Comment: @John Brevik What do you mean? If $-x$ and $-y$ are both finite sums of powers of $p$, then $-(x+y)$ is likewise a finite sum of powers of $p$, no?

Comment: I may misunderstand your meaning. The way you have defined it, p-adics that are not a finite sum of powers are less than 0, yes? You can add two such and get a finite sum. Is this not a problem?

Comment: No. They are not comparable with 0.  In particular, this is not a total order.

Comment: OK. Sorry if I am taking a while to get up to speed, but nobody else is answering :) For x an infinite p-adic, what is the least upper bound of x and 0?

Comment: No worries.  I'm glad at least someone cares!  If by an infinite $p$-adic you mean something like $-1=(p-1)+(p-1)p+(p-1)p^2+\cdots$, then, at least in this case, $\sup \{ 0,-1\} =0$.  In particular, this ordering has the odd property that, while the sum of any finitely many positive numbers is positive, the sum of infinitely many positive numbers can be negative.  Or the same statement without my language:  the sum of infinitely many absolute values can be the additive inverse of an absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have the least upper-bound property.

Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{Q}_p$ be non-empty and bounded, so that there are $m,M\in \mathbb{Q}_p$ such that, if $x\in S$, then $m\leq x\leq M$.  By replacing $S$ with $S-m$ we may without loss of generality assume that $m=0$.  We then have that $0\leq x\leq M$.

Note that every non-zero element of $S$ is a finite sum of powers of $p$.  In general, there are many ways of writing an element as a finite sum of powers of $p$, and so to aid our argument, we define a canonical way of writing each $x\in S$:  when writing $x$ as a finite sum of powers of $p$, always group the terms into the largest powers of $p$ as possible.  (For example, we write a sum of $p$ terms, each of which is $p^2$, as $p^3$.)  Hereafter, we always write $x$ in canonical form as $x=a_mp^m+a_{m+1}p^{m+1}+a_{m+2}p^{m+2}+\cdots +a_np^n$ for $a_k\in \{ 0,\ldots ,p-1\}$.

If $M=0$, then because this is a partial order (this requires an easy check), it follows that $S=\{ 0\}$ and we are done, so we may as well suppose that $0\leq x<M$ for $x\in S$, in which case we can write $M=a_mp^m+\cdots +a_np^n$.  Now if $x\in S$ is non-zero, we must have that $x=b_ip^i+\cdots +b_jp^j$, and also that
$$
c_kp^k+\cdots +c_lp^l=M-x=(a_mp^m+\cdots +a_np^n)-(b_ip^i+\cdots +b_jp^j)
$$
because $M-x>0$.  Re-arranging, we must have
$$
(b_ip^i+\cdots +b_jp^j)+(c_kp^k+\cdots +c_lp^l)=a_mp^m+a_np^n.
$$
After re-writing the left-hand side in canonical form, for every power of $p$ between $p^i$ and $p^j$, either that power or $p$ times that power will remain (the power itself if we don't 'carry' or the power times $p$ if we do).  In particular, every power of $p$ that appeared in $x$ must itself appear in $M$ or $p$ times that power must appear in $M$.  Altogether, there are only finitely many possibilities for such a power.

In particular, this implies that $S$ is *finite*, and so, because the order restricted to $S$ is a total order (in fact, all integers are comparable with each other because one of the differences will be a finite sum of $p^0=1$s), we simply have that $\sup S=\max S$, and in particular, $S$ does have a least upper-bound.